# how can we find estimated time for query in DB2

Tags: db2

how can we identify the estimated time left for a query in DB2 and if the estimated time is huge then how can we kill the already running query

Comment: Platform and version would probably help.

Comment: All RDBMSs use/generate something called an `EXPLAIN` plan.  It's how the db knows what indicies to use to best get the results.  You can ask it for one manually (runtime is going to be an estimate, though).  At least DB2 will cancel/ask for confirmation on queries it thinks will take to long on its own (I assume the timeout can be adjusted).   What's the context in which you need this information?

Answer (score 0):

As Clockwork-Muse pointed out, you can run EXPLAIN to find out the estimated query execution time. Note that this estimation is only as accurate as the RUNSTATS information in your database.

If the query is already running, you can use DB2 FORCE APPLICATION command to terminate your application that is running this query.